# How can i call Intent's startActivty() for an Activity class from a normal java class?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am working on **ocr-vision** by google. I can detect text from an **OcrGraphic.java** which does not extends Activity , i want to send the extracted values to an activity file which has edit text for the particular texts, the moment it goes inside **timer run()** method it throws null pointer exception on null reference.

My code is given down:

OcrGraphic.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.amirfirdaus.mrztutorial.Model.SkanIkadValues;
import com.example.amirfirdaus.mrztutorial.ScanIkadResult;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.Line;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.Text;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
 * Graphic instance for rendering TextBlock position, size, and ID within an 
associated graphic
 * overlay view.
 */
public class OcrGraphic extends GraphicOverlay.Graphic {

private static Context context;
private int mId;

private static final int TEXT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;

private static Paint sRectPaint;
private static Paint sTextPaint;
private final TextBlock mText;
private boolean isBirthday;
private boolean isExpiry;
private boolean isPassport;
String birthday = "";
String expiry = "";
String passport = "";

OcrGraphic(GraphicOverlay overlay, TextBlock text) {
    super(overlay);

    mText = text;


    if (sRectPaint == null) {
        sRectPaint = new Paint();
        sRectPaint.setColor(TEXT_COLOR);
        sRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        sRectPaint.setStrokeWidth(4.0f);
    }

    if (sTextPaint == null) {
        sTextPaint = new Paint();
        sTextPaint.setColor(TEXT_COLOR);
        sTextPaint.setTextSize(54.0f);
    }
    // Redraw the overlay, as this graphic has been added.
    postInvalidate();
}
public static Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

public int getId() {
    return mId;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.mId = id;
}

public TextBlock getTextBlock() {
    return mText;
}

/**
 * Checks whether a point is within the bounding box of this graphic.
 * The provided point should be relative to this graphic's containing overlay.
 *
 * @param x An x parameter in the relative context of the canvas.
 * @param y A y parameter in the relative context of the canvas.
 * @return True if the provided point is contained within this graphic's bounding box.
 */
public boolean contains(float x, float y) {
    if (mText == null) {
        return false;
    }
    RectF rect = new RectF(mText.getBoundingBox());
    rect.left = translateX(rect.left);
    rect.top = translateY(rect.top);
    rect.right = translateX(rect.right);
    rect.bottom = translateY(rect.bottom);
    return (rect.left < x && rect.right > x && rect.top < y && rect.bottom > y);
}

/**
 * Draws the text block annotations for position, size, and raw value on the supplied canvas.
 */
@Override
public void draw(final Canvas canvas)
{
    if (mText == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Draws the bounding box around the TextBlock.
    RectF rect = new RectF(mText.getBoundingBox());
    rect.left = translateX(rect.left);
    rect.top = translateY(rect.top);
    rect.right = translateX(rect.right);
    rect.bottom = translateY(rect.bottom);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, sRectPaint);

    // Break the text into multiple lines and draw each one according to its own bounding box.
  List<Line> lineComponents;
    lineComponents = (List<Line>) mText.getComponents();
    //List<? extends Text> textComponents = mText.getComponents();
    for (Text currentText : lineComponents) {
        float left = translateX(currentText.getBoundingBox().left);
        float bottom = translateY(currentText.getBoundingBox().bottom);
        canvas.drawText(currentText.getValue(), left, bottom, sTextPaint);

        if (!(currentText.getValue() == null))
        {

           Log.e("OCrGraphic", "Text detected! " + currentText.getValue());

            if (isBirthday == false && !currentText.getValue().contains("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") || currentText.getValue().startsWith("0") && currentText.getValue().contains("+-0123456789/-#")) {
                Log.e("currentTextBirthday", currentText.getValue());
                birthday = "";
                birthday = currentText.getValue();
                isBirthday = true;
                SkanIkadValues.setBirthday(birthday);
               // Log.e("OCrGraphic", "Text detected! " + currentText.getValue());
            }

            if (isExpiry == false && !currentText.getValue().contains("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") || currentText.getValue().startsWith("0") && currentText.getValue().contains("+-0123456789/-#")) {
                Log.e("currentTextExpiry", currentText.getValue());
                expiry = "";
                expiry = currentText.getValue();
                isExpiry = true;
                SkanIkadValues.setExpiry(expiry);
               // Log.e("OCrGraphic", "Text detected! " + currentText.getValue());

            }
            if (isPassport == false && currentText.getValue().contains("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") || currentText.getValue().startsWith("0") && currentText.getValue().contains("+-0123456789/-#")) {
                Log.e("currentTextPassport", currentText.getValue());
                passport = "";
                passport = currentText.getValue();
                isPassport = true;
                SkanIkadValues.setPassport(passport);

                //  Log.e("OCrGraphic", "Text detected! " + currentText.getValue());

            }
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  // if(!expiry.equals("") && !birthday.equals("") && !passport.equals(""))


                    Intent next = new Intent(getContext(),ScanIkadResult.class);
                    next.putExtra("passport", passport);
                    next.putExtra("expiry", expiry);
                    next.putExtra("birthday", birthday);
                    next.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    // intent.putStringArrayListExtra("contactsList",stringList);
                    context.startActivity(next);
                          /* Log.e("CBname",skanIkadValues.getName());*/



                }
            },2000,2000);

        }
    }
}


     /* private static class ApplicationController {
       public static Context getContext() {
          return context;
       }*/
     }
```

Comment: You never assign a value to `context`.

Comment: How can i assign value to the context ? i am little confused because it is normal java file

Comment: @androminor, Use #ADM 's solution, It will work

Answer (score 2):

Because you never assigned a value to `context`. Instead of using `static` Context you can modify the constructor to `Context` as a parameter.

```
 public class OcrGraphic extends GraphicOverlay.Graphic {
    private Context context;

    OcrGraphic(GraphicOverlay overlay, TextBlock text, Context context) {
        super(overlay);
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Since `GraphicOverlay.Graphic` is not a `View` you can not directly use  `getContext()`.

Comment: I tried to add context following you as per the requirement but had to make context in two other files " OcrCaptureActivity " and " OcrDetectorPrcocessor". The context is working and taking me to desired result activity but there is memory leaking happening which making the result activity continiously reload infinitely . i can not stop also could not find any solution ? any insight ?

Comment: There is no error . the out put i am receiving is:  E/OCrGraphic: Text detected! Money
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=24KB, data=29KB
       After code cache collection, code=24KB, data=29KB
       Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=55KB, data=61KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=55KB, data=61KB
       Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB

Comment: memory leak is not the cause of that . You probably missed some callback or some method got recursively called . Try to debug each step of your code . To detect Memory leak Use [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary).